# how to disable multiselect on change or on select event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

this combobox contains some x values when i select 10th value i need to disable multiple select option,other than 10th value mean this option should be multiple select

```
 <select class="easyui-combobox" multiple="multiple" multiline="true"  style="width: 150px;height:50px;" id="inc_combo_ems_hour" style="width: 75px;">
                        <option value="00">00</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>
                        <option value="03">03</option>
                        <option value="04">04</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option></select>    


    $('#inc_combo_ems_hour').combobox({
            onSelect: function(){
                var val=[];
        val=$('#inc_combo_ems_hour').combobox('getValues');

        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        if(val[i]!="null"){
        if(val[i]=="*")
        {
        $('#inc_combo_ems_hour').combobox({
                        required: false,
                        novalidate: false,
                multiple: false,
                value:"*"
                        });
        }
        }
        else if(val[i]!=null && val[i] !="*"){
        $('#inc_combo_ems_hour').combobox('setValue',val[i])
        $('#inc_combo_ems_hour').combobox({
                        required: true,
                        novalidate: false,
                multiple: true,
                value:val[i]
                        });
        }
        }
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a functional solution:

```js
$('#inc_combo_ems_hour').change(function(){

  if ( $('#inc_combo_ems_hour option:selected').val() == 10 ) {

    $(this).removeAttr('multiple');

  } else {

    $(this).attr('multiple', 'multiple');

  }

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<select class="easyui-combobox" multiple="multiple" multiline="true"  style="width: 150px;height:50px;" id="inc_combo_ems_hour" style="width: 75px;">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Or see this [alternate demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjz0art0/2/)

Comment: i need to multiple select other than 10th value

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will help you.

```js
$('#sle').change(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('multiple');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select id="sle" class="easyui-combobox" multiple="multiple" >
   <option value="00">00</option>
   <option value="01">01</option>
   <option value="02">02</option>
   <option value="03">03</option>
   <option value="04">04</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove multiple selection when option is 10:

```
$('#sle').change(function(){
  if ( $(this).val() == 10 ) {
      $(this).removeAttr('multiple');
  } else {
      $(this).attr('multiple', 'multiple');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery 1.6 onwards**,
always use the selectedIndex as the option value may change.

```
$('#inc_combo_ems_hour').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.prop("selectedIndex") === 9 ) {
        $this.removeAttr('multiple');
    } else {
        $this.attr('multiple', 'multiple');
    }
});
```